# Looking for a good way to write multiple virtual "files" to one system file

Tags: file, file-io, filesystems

I have an application where there are multiple processes. They share the reading and writing of a set of files that grows over time. I'd rather not expose thousands of files to the user's environment, where it would be much easier for them to accidentally modify or delete one of them. Is there an API that will allow reasonably high performant writes and reads to a virtual file system that is ultimately a single file on the hard drive? I would need it in either C# or C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use SQLite, or any key-value store with good BLOB values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, our [SolFS OS edition](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) provides exactly the API you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

There's a genre of things called key-value stores that do exactly what you want. BerkeleyDB and Tokyo Cabinet / Tokyo Tyrant are good examples. They're simpler and faster than relational databases. The keys they store things under are arbitrary byte strings, so you can use filesystem-like paths. If you use a B-tree organisation, you can do prefix queries, to implement something like a directory listing.

You mention needing access from multiple processes: I'm not sure how well BerkeleyDB handles that, but Tokyo Tyrant does it fine.